# Python - .format in .format

Tags: python, format

I really like using the .format for calling command and not repeat myself. I have this function

```
def function_1(command):
    subprocess.call(['{0} ; {1} ; {2}; {3}'.format(var_0, var_1, var_2, command)])
```

and then in another function

```
def function_2()
    function_1('command {0} {2}')
```

I want to use the variables that were defined in the first function by simply calling them as if I was in the first function. I don't want to repeat myself by having a .format in both function.

If that string is '{0}' in the second function, why the compiler doesn't pick it up and see it as the same as '{0}' in the first function. When you passed by arguments the { }, it doesn't pick it up ?

Is there a way to do it in a simple way ? After all I want to have something like this :

```
subprocess.call(['{0}; {1}; {2}; command {0} {2}'.format(var_0, var_1, var_2)])
```

This doesn't work for now. It prints this...

```
{0} {2}
```

Comment: "_I want to use the variables that were defined in the first function by simply calling them as if I was in the first function._" Can you elaborate?

Comment: Just to add something that not many people implement yet, is that in Python 3.6 ["f-strings"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#how-to-denote-f-strings) now allow you to use `f'this is a string with a {VAR_NAME_HERE}'` instead of using `.format`

Comment: If that string is  '{0}' in the second function, why the compiler doesn't pick it up and see it as the same as '{0}' in the first function. When you passed by arguments the { }, it doesn't pick it up ?

Answer (score 1):

Concat the previous string with `command`. You don't need formatting for the new placeholders held in `command`:

```
def function_1(command):
    s = '{0} ; {1} ; {2}; ' + command
    subprocess.call([s.format(var_0, var_1, var_2)])
```

The placeholders in `command` are now used in the formatting done in the following line.

To make the positioning of `command` more flexible, you can double up the curly braces, and apply a pre-formatting step.

```
def function_1(command):
    s = '{{0}} ; {{1}} ; {{2}}; {0}'.format(command)
    subprocess.call([s.format(var_0, var_1, var_2)])
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> '{{0}} {0}'.format('command {0} {2}')
'{0} command {0} {2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what your are expecting.

```
 subprocess.call(['{var0}; {var1}; {var2}; command {var0} {var2}'.format(var0=var_0, var1=var_1, var2=var_2)])
```